# building a dynamic request with child attributes

Tags: c#, json, formatting, json.net

I need to create a dynamic request with child attributes and I am not entirely sure how to do it.  I have newtonsoft.json installed, so I was thinking of making a series of classes maybe, and then serialize them, but I also have to pass in the credentials/consumer keys Oauth stuff.

```
{
  "type": "email",
  "subject": "Creating a case via the API",
  "priority": 4,
  "status": "open",
  "labels": [
    "Spam",
    "Ignore"
  ],
"message": {
    "direction": "in",
    "status": "received",
    "to": "someone@desk.com",
    "from": "someone-else@desk.com",
  }
```

So to have that request above, would I create a main class, which would have properties like type/subject/status and then it would have my other class message in it as well. I am just trying to figure out how the serializing converts the classes

Comment: Which part you can't get done by “making a series of classes maybe, and then serialize them”?

Comment: well, I was just wondering if this is the best idea. I will update my question

Comment: You need to define what you mean by *dynamic*.

Comment: dynamic as in some of those fields are not require, or like label it may have more than two labels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may this help you

```
public class dataObj
{
   public string type { get; set; }
   public string subject { get; set; }
   public int priority { get; set; }
   public string status { get; set; }
   public IList<string> labels { get; set; }
   public IDictionary<string, string> message { get; set; }
}



private void testbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            string json = @"{
                ""type"": ""email"",
                ""subject"": ""Creating a case via the API"",
                ""priority"": 4,
                ""status"": ""open"",
                ""labels"": [
                ""Spam"",
                ""Ignore""
                ],
            ""message"": {
            ""direction"": ""in"",
            ""status"": ""received"",
            ""to"": ""someone@desk.com"",
            ""from"": ""someone-else@desk.com""
            }
          }";
            dataObj data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dataObj>(json);

        }
        catch { 

        }
    }
```